# Format DateTime when get data from backend in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, date, format

I use angularJs to get data from serve and it return datetime have

```
format:"/Date(1551579360000)/".
```

How can I convert format datetime in this case

```
DistrictId: 1
DistrictName: "01"
Id: 1
IncidentDate: "/Date(1551579360000)/"
IncidentTyleId: 2
IncidentTyleName: "Firearm Discharge"
Name: "2019-0000294"
NotificationDate: "/Date(1551546000000)/"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get `Date`

```
new Date(("/Date(1551579360000)/").match(/\d+/)[0] * 1)
```

2. Format `Date` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom angular filter like below:

```
.filter('dateFormat', function() {
    return function(dt) {
        var dt = new Date(dt);
        return (dt.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dt.getDate()+'/'+dt.getFullYear();
    };
  })
```

convert json date to a javascript date

```
var date = new Date(Number("/Date(1551579360000)/".replace(/\D/g, '')));
```

and then use the filter on js date object

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: Affect recieving date format

You have provided pretty weird date format. If you can affect it, then it is better to recieve date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, e. g. `2019-05-09T14:08:52.335`. In this case you can simply use this string for `Date` constructor:

```
new Date("2019-05-09T14:08:52.335")
```

and use native methods of `Date.prototype` (like `.toLocaleDateString`) or format it by on your own

```js
var ISODateString = "2019-05-09T14:08:52.335"
var date = new Date(ISODateString)

console.log(date)
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString())
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())

function formatDate(date) {
  return `${
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")}.${
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")}.${
    date.getFullYear()
   }`
}

function formatTime(date) {
  return `${
    date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${
    date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${
    date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0")
  }`
}

console.log(formatDate(date))
console.log(formatTime(date))
```

---

## Solution 2: using `eval()` (TREAT AS UNSAFE!)

Speechless

```js
var recievedDate = "/Date(1557400796087)/"
var date = eval(`new ${recievedDate.replace(/\//g, "")}`)

console.log(date)
```

Note that I provided this solution for variability and you should not use it, because it has code-injection vulnerability.

---

## Solution 3: Extract timestamp

If you cannot affect the response, the only way is to extract timestamp from response. Then you can use format guides from **Solution 1**

```js
var recievedDate = "/Date(1551546000000)/"
var timestamp = Number(recievedDate.replace(/\D/g, ""))
var date = new Date(timestamp)

console.log(date)
```

That's it!
Hope that helps :)